# Why does Javascript show me the wrong date?

Tags: javascript, date, object

Consider the following date object which is created in JavaScript.

```
var date = new Date("2017-09-07T16:46:06.000Z");
```

This date object should be equivalent to Sep 7 2017 4:46:06 PM

However, in the browser console, when I type the following:

```
console.log(date);
```

The following is returned:

> Fri Sep 08 2017 02:46:06 GMT+1000 (E. Australia Standard Time)

The time is wrong. (It actually is today's date, but the time is completely wrong).

**Key points of confusion:**

- My computer timezone is set to GMT+1000 (Australia/Brisbane)
- When I created the date object, I did not specify the timezone, therefore it should conform to my systems timezone
- When I log the date object to the console, it is still using GMT+1000 (Australia/Brisbane) but the date is different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you created the date, you **did** specify a timezone. That `Z` at the end means *Zulu* or Greenwich Mean Time. Your computer is 10 hours off from GMT, so it adjusts to your local timezone for display.

If you want the date to be in your local time zone, remove the `Z`

Comment: No, don't remove the Z. The string is being parsed correctly, removing the Z means it will be treated as local so will represent a different moment in time (10 hours different for the OP).

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = new Date("2017-09-07T16:46:06.000Z");
```

So it looks like the `Z` at the end of your date string is meant to represent UTC or Zulu time

```
var date = new Date("2017-09-07T16:46:06.000");
```

should  be the correct solution